# Error : Shell script returns unary operator is expected error message

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

i am fixing a given shell script and i am getting following error message

```
line 322: [: ==: unary operator expected
```

this error is returned from this line.

```
 if [ $4 == "managed?.out" ];then
```

could someone explain me what makes this error

Also could someone explain what is the purpose of using ? in the"managed?.out"

thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to quote `$4`:

```
if [ "$4" == "managed?.out" ];then
```

Comment: Could you explain why exactly you need to do this? @codaddict

Comment: Yes, I'd be interested in the answer to @H_7's question as well.

Answer (score 1):

change the if statement to

```
if [ "$4" == "managed?.out" ];then
```

The double-quotes are only necessary as you use $4, if your variable would be $string, you would not need them.

should "?" be interpreted as a bash-wildcard? if yes, you need to use

```
if [[ "$4" == managed?.out ]];then
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if [[ $4 == "managed?.out" ]];then
```

Comment: this is a separate question. what is the purpose of using ? sign in the managed?.out text.